# Set Bootable Partition Command Line

Tags: parted

How to I set the bootable partition using the command line in parted?

Ideally I would like a numbered list so I can select which partition to boot from easily.

Comment: How to set a partition flag is explained in the manual and should be a trivial task... You can't have numbered lists when you `set` a flag but you can always print the device layout (which is a numbered list) and inspect it before setting any flags.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

I  use fdisk. before to apply this  I recommend to work with a live CD or USB and back up your data.

First check if any bootable partition is present like in my system  wich "/dev/sda1" is the bootable partition :

```
fdisk -l /dev/sda                                                      

Disk /dev/sda: 500.1 GB, 500107862016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 60801 cylinders, total 976773168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00003256

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1    *       2048   959991807   479994880   83  Linux
/dev/sda2       959993854   976766975     8386561    5  Extended
/dev/sda5       959993856   976766975     8386560   82  Linux swap / Solaris
```

If there is not any boot partition do like this with root login :

```
fdisk  /dev/sda
Command (m for help): m

Command action
   a   toggle a bootable flag
   b   edit bsd disklabel
   c   toggle the dos compatibility flag
   d   delete a partition
   l   list known partition types
   m   print this menu
   n   add a new partition
   o   create a new empty DOS partition table
   p   print the partition table
   q   quit without saving changes
   s   create a new empty Sun disklabel
   t   change a partition's system id
   u   change display/entry units
   v   verify the partition table
   w   write table to disk and exit
   x   extra functionality (experts only)

Command (m for help): a
Partition number (1-5):
```

You've to type 1 if you want to make bootable the partition 1 or and following  2 if you want to make bootable the second partition etc...

and aply the modification with "w" like this

```
Command (m for help): w
```

For modify the table of your disk and make the desired partition bootable.

In hoping that help

Comment: fdisk  appears to not have bootable flag option any longer ... on archlinux install attempt on  20190712

Comment: With fdisk I created the System EFI partition and it automatically had the bootable flag with GPT which I could see with `parted1`, even though I could not set it manually any more. Possibly choosing the correct partition type is sufficient.

Answer (score 32):

With the `print` command you ge the partition number (first column). Let us say it is 1. To make it bootable:

```
(parted) set 1 boot on
```

Comment: Worth noting that you can do this in the GUI very easily; right click the partition you want, flags, click boot.

Comment: @robert, Thank you for the right answer to the question!

Comment: Interactionless one-liner form: `parted /dev/sdX set 1 boot on`. Prints: `Information: You may need to update /etc/fstab.`

Comment: what do you mean by `print` command? just `print`? `parted print`?

Answer (score 2):

OS X https://qwiek.wordpress.com/ "fdisk" then `flag 1` to make first partition bootable.

Comment: The question cannot be about OS X, as it is about Linux !

Comment: BSD is unix? :)