# Grub bootup steps

Tags: boot, linux-kernel, grub2, gentoo, hexdump

Am installing gentoo. At Grub bootloader but can’t seem to find kernel, which is odd because it’s existence was verified before restarting the machine. There doesn’t seem to be a “root” or “kernel” command, nor “vmlinuz”. Hexdumping gpt1 and gpt2 (the only two partitions with recognizable file systems to grub) says they’re not bootable disks.

Edit: Made some progress—found the vmlinuz and initramfs with “ls (hd0, partition)/“. Used “linux” command and initrd to set and handle boot. Used “boot” to boot. Oddly enough, the partition with the correct filesystem for boot seems to require a rescue shell.

Here are the instructions I’m following: https://christitus.com/grub-rescue/

Comment: Does your system use a classic BIOS or is it a UEFI system? There are major differences in the boot process between the two. If it's a UEFI system, please run `efibootmgr -v` as root and edit the output into your question. Also, please add a link to the instructions you're following or otherwise describe *exactly* what you're doing. Your talk about hexdumping partitions indicates you may be knowledgeable about BIOS-style boot process, but if your system is UEFI, much of that knowledge will no longer apply.

Comment: What does “mount all partitions” mean using the gentoo livecd? Don’t have to download a new tarball, right?

Comment: https://youtu.be/AyZa8h68wbI

Answer (score 1):

Use this checklist to troubleshoot common booting problems [with Gentoo]:

1. Ensure that your `vmlinuz` and initrd/initramfs are present on boot partition, not `/boot` directory on root filesystem.
2. Boot with Gentoo Live CD, mount all partitions, chroot and regenerate Grub config with `grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg` (from chroot).
3. Use `parted` or `fdisk` to enable ESP (EFI System Partition) flag on your boot partition. After this, reboot.

Answer (score 0):

> Hexdumping gpt1 and gpt2 (the only two partitions with recognizable
> file systems to grub) says they’re not bootable disks.

you can change the boot flag with gparted (sorry i don't know how to this with command line, but the answer is here: [Set Bootable Partition Command Line](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/343429/set-bootable-partition-command-line))

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.

Comment: i linked to a good answer because i can't comment...